# Replicate a directory and file names n times

Tags: shell, files, ksh, file-copy

I have folder which has some data (files) in that with the name

```
201311261418

And a file 201311261418.eob
```

In my scenario I need to replicate this folder and file names n times with the appended numbers of the count.

Desired Output, if needed to replicate 10 times:

```
2013112614181  
2013112614182  
2013112614183  
.  
.  
.  
20131126141810
```

And for files:

```
2013112614181.eob  
2013112614182.eob  
2013112614183.eob  
.  
.  
.  
20131126141810.eob
```

I'm using ksh on AIX.

Comment: Do you actually want the starts '*' in your folder and filenames? Are there other acceptable characters?

Answer (score 2):

The following script does this:

```
#!/bin/bash

INDIR=/path/to/where/your/file/is/stored
OUTDIR=/path/to/where/you/want/your/folders/to/be/created

# In the following line, 10 is the number of folders/files that will be created. -w means append a 0 before the numbers: 01 02 03 ... 10, instead of 1 2 3 ... 10. You can remove it if you want.

for i in `seq -w 1 10`; do 
    mkdir ${OUTDIR}/201311261418${i}
    cp ${INDIR}/201311261418.eob ${OUTDIR}/201311261418${i}.eob
done
```

Comment: This would work on Linux, but not on AIX. You can replace bash by ksh, but there's no `seq` utility on AIX.

Comment: in that case, you could replace the line "for i in `seq -w 1 10`; do" for "for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do", or replace it with "for i in {1..10}; do"

Comment: @Vincent: When i tried the below piece of code 
`for i in {1..10}; do
echo $i
done`

The output is as given below
`{1..10}`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. If I understand correctly, you want to create multiple copies of a file, adding a number at the end of the name but preserving the extension.

```
#!/bin/ksh
n=$1; shift
ret=0
for file; do
  # Decompose the file name to isolate the extension part
  dir=$(dirname -- "$file")
  file=$(basename -- "$file")
  base=${file%%.*}
  extension=${file#"$base"}
  # Make $n copies
  for ((i=1; i<=n; i++)); do
    cp -- "$dir/$base$extension" "$dir/$base$i$extension" || ret=1
  done
done
exit $ret
```

Usage (where `make-copies` is the script above):

```
make-copies 10 201311261418 201311261418.eob
```

You may want to add a separator before the number, e.g.

```
    cp -- "$dir/$base$extension" "$dir/$base-$i$extension" || ret=1
```

If you want to pad the number with zeroes so that they have the same width, change the beginning of the script to

```
#!/bin/ksh
n=$1; shift
start=1${n//?/0}
…
```

and replace the inner loop by

```
  for ((i=$((start+1)); i<=$((start+n)); i++)); do
    cp -- "$dir/$base$extension" "$dir/$base${i#1}$extension" || ret=1
  done
```

Comment: :When tried your code m getting a sytax error `ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error: `(' is not expected.`

Comment: @Ram Is that on the `for ((…))` line? Does AIX still not have ksh93? Try `i=1; while [[ $i -le $n ]]; do … i=$((i+1)); done`